# Deleting rows conditionally in r

Tags: r, duplicates

I want to delete rows that have duplicated dates AND ID's. I always want to keep the first row when deleting duplicates.

```
**df1**
ID  Date        score1  score2
73  2014-05-04  5       7
73  2014-05-04  5       8
73  2014-07-12  2       7
73  2014-07-12  4       3
79  2014-09-11  3       7
82  2014-05-04  5       7
82  2014-05-04  5       6

**Wanteddf**
ID  Date        score1  score2
73  2014-05-04  5       7
73  2014-07-12  2       7
79  2014-09-11  3       7
82  2014-05-04  5       7
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Your question is basically asking someone to write your code.

Comment: I was trying something very similar to @akrun 's answer but I was just making a silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% distinct(Date, ID)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `base R`

```
 df1[!duplicated(df1[1:2]),]
 #   ID       Date score1 score2
 #1 73 2014-05-04      5      7
 #3 73 2014-07-12      2      7
 #5 79 2014-09-11      3      7
 #6 82 2014-05-04      5      7
```

Comment: So I'm looking back at my data and for some reason this function deleted a lot of my data when they were not duplicates, but when I used @jeremycg it worked fine

Comment: @Swanny I tested it and it works fine.  For example. `v1 <- 1:9;v1[!duplicated(v1)]#
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` or using this example `df1 <- data.frame(v1=1:9, v2=c(1,1,2:5,6:8)); nrow(df1[!duplicated(df1),])#[1] 9`

Comment: @Swanny Any chance you can post a small example that reproduce the problem.  I would suggest to use `dput` i.e. `dput(smalldata)`

Comment: It's got a lot of confidential information for a study so I can't really, but thanks for all your help anyways.

Comment: @Swanny You don't have divulge the confidential files.  You can just mimic some example that shows the problem.  I couldn't reproduce the behaviour you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Using [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
unique(df1, by=c("Date","ID"))
```

Ensure to use recent 1.9.5 version.
After resolving [data.table#635: Delete rows by reference](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635) it can be even faster.